# representing x, y coordinates as numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dict containing cell names and their position(x, y coordinates) as values.I am able to create a 2*2 numpy array for keys. However I am not able to do same with values. I am trying to create an 2*2 array for the values with each element as (x,y) and not [x,y].

```
cells_position
Out[367]: 
{'A1': [-28, 28],
 'A2': [-28, 20],     
 'B1': [-20, 28],
 'B2': [-20, 20]}

cells_array=np.array(list(cells_position.keys()))
cells_array=np.reshape(cells_array, (2, 2)).transpose()

cells_array
Out[369]: 
array([['A1', 'B1'],
       ['A2', 'B2']], dtype='<U2')
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Intended output:

```
[[(-28, 28), (-20, 28)],
[(-28, 20), (-20,20)]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by elements as `(x, y)` not `[x, y]`? do you mean an array of tuples?

Comment: @Navaro I have updated the question. Yes I meant array of tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to create an empty array of dtype object and then populate it with your values.

The following produces the intended output or me.

```
import numpy as np
cells_position = {'A1': [-28, 28], 'A2': [-28, 20],'B1': [-20, 28], 'B2': [-20,20]}
values = [tuple(value) for value in cells_position.values()]
cells_array = np.empty(len(values), dtype=object)
cells_array[:] = values
cells_array=np.reshape(cells_array, (2, 2)).transpose()
```